# Make all instances of part of word italic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, expressionengine

I'm using expressionengine as a CMS, after the page is loaded, I need to find 'arbesthealth' and make it ar*best*health,  What would be the best way to do this?  Jquery after document ready?  can it be done with CSS?

note: I can't do it on the cms side because EE doesn't allow tags inside the title fields so it needs to be done on output.  I guess I could do it with a substr in php, but I'm just curious to the other ways that this would be possible.

Comment: I believe you need to add some relevant code since people are seeing this off topic

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to manipulate `innerHTML` (directly, or through jQuery's `html` function), but that will destroy and recreate all of the elements, which isn't ideal — not least because any event handlers attached to them will get removed.

But a simple recursive function processing text nodes and inserting `strong` elements as necessary isn't difficult. [My answer to this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5158204/157247) shows how to do that, walking through the text nodes and using `Text#splitText` to split them up and insert elements. Sounds like a lot more work than it is.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a tag inside the word like this:

```
$('.content').wrapInTag({
    words: ['best'],
    tag: '<span>'
});
```

See [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/fw6Pk/123/)

I added in ***.content*** but you can add it wherever the cms has the container

---

****UPDATE****

As mentioned this will effect all so lets try this method:

```
html().replace
```

[**SPECIFIC FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/fw6Pk/125/)

Comment: That will blow away any event handlers assigned to the elements by jQuery or `addEventListener` prior to running it. So it would have to be first thing, before anything hooked up any handlers.

Comment: I really like this, but how could I alter this so that it doesn't find the word "best" unless it is in the occurance of arbesthealth?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder has a point...hence why you need to know what class is this word/logo/ title specifically since you could have a paragraph with the word 'best'..given you might have it on a paragraph.