# Applying str.search on content of document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I am just beginning to learn Javascript, so my terminology might be off, apologies.

I am writing a Tampermonkey script. This should search a page for a keyword ("beer") and, when found, have the keyword highlighted in red. Right now, I am only concerned about HOW to search the applicable part of the HTML file and trigger the highlighting action:

1) Can I search the string in the below

```
<div id="appLongDescription"
style="white-space: normal; word-wrap: break-word;">
This sentence contains beer.
</div>
```

by doing this?

```
var name = document.getElementById("appLongDescription").str.search("bier");
```

2) and then build a condition for the highlighter based on whether

```
name != -1
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can get the text of a div tag using only javascript (no jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370204/how-can-get-the-text-of-a-div-tag-using-only-javascript-no-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to access string inside div `appLongDescription`. First you need to access element `appLongDescription`. You can do this via following code: `document.getElementById("appLongDescription");` After this you need to call `innerHTML` like this: `document.getElementById("appLongDescription").innerHTML` Please see [`innerHTML`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) docs. After this you could check whether string of`appLongDescription` div contains some substring via calling [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) function. Please see docs.
full javascript code would look like this:

```
var appLongDescriptionStr = document.getElementById("appLongDescription").innerHTML; 
var beerIndex = appLongDescriptionStr.indexOf("beer");
```

`beerIndex` will contain the index of string `beer` inside `appLongDescription` inner string. if `beerIndex` is `-1`, this mins means that string `beer` was not found.

Comment: Thx Tornike, this broke it down for me!

Comment: And @MKKirk , if this answer also works better for you, please [mark it so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

HTML element instances have no `str` property. They have [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), and [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) (and [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)) which they inherit from `Node`. Those all return strings containing the contents of the HTML element (as markup, or as text), so you could call `search` on them, yes.

**However**, if you want to highlight the text, you'll need to know its position within the *text node* that it's in, so you can split the node there and wrap the text in a `span` or similar. You *don't* want to just assign back to `innerHTML`, because doing that destroys the elements and then replaces them with newly-created elements from the string, which loses even handlers. Instead, you have to recursively loop through the child and descendant odes of that element, and for the text nodes, look for the text within that node. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5158204/157247) shows how to do that.

Comment: Thx T.J. Crowder. This takes me in the right direction.

Comment: @MKKirk - I've added a second paragraph aboev with more information on how to do this.