# Using Javascript to create a link on raw text

Tags: javascript, html

I am using an editor which doesn't allow links or code to be added. For example, I can add the following:

```
[url=http://example.com]This is a test[/url]
```

This will then show on the website exactly as it is shown above.

How can I then use Javascript to turn the above into a link, but only show **This is a test** but with a link on it?

Comment: If your editor escapes the HTML so the code is actually rendered as text it does NOT allow HTML.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5158204/157247) to the linked question. All you need to do is come up with the regex for your `url` pattern, which is fairly simple: `/\[url\s*=\s*([^\]]+)\]([^[]+)\[\/url]/` :-)